# What is the difference between "CPU samples" tab and "Thread CPU Time" tab of visualvm sampler?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, operating-system, visualvm

When I use visualvm, I get confused about "CPU samples" tab and "Thread CPU Time" tab of the sampler. The following screenshots show the same thread "Monitor Ctrl-Break" respectively in these two tabs:

[CPU time in "CPU samples" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MW6AY.png) is 1082903ms.

[CPU time in "Thread CPU Time" tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJgqc.png) is only 15.6ms!

My questions:

1. Why the CPU time in these two tabs differ so much?
2. What is the meaning of these two CPU time? In other words, which parts do these two CPU time consist of?

Looking forward for some replies. Thank you all.

Answer (score 0):

The difference comes from the fact that the JVM does not know whether a native method blocks or not.

Consider a simple example:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

If the standard input is console, and a user have not typed anything, the method `InputStream.read` will block. If the standard input is a file on a disk, `read` will immediately return the first byte of the file. The JVM does not distinguish these two cases; it happens on the OS level. From the JVM perspective, a thread executing `FileInputStream.read` method is always in `RUNNABLE` state, even though the underlying I/O may block on the OS level.

CPU sampler in VisualVM treats `RUNNABLE` threads as if they consume CPU.
On the contrary, `Thread CPU time` tab gets statistics directly from the OS, and thus shows the real CPU usage.

So if a thread blocks inside a native method like `read`, it is considered runnable from the JVM perspective, but idle from the OS perspective. In fact, such method does not consume CPU time, but VisualVM sees that a thread is `RUNNABLE` and counts it as busy.

VisualVM is not the only profiler that suffers from this problem. This is actually a common fallacy of all sampling profilers based on the standard Java API to get thread stack traces. Find more details in [my presentation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TDpbt4thECc).

Comment: Firstly, thank you for your answer. As you say, can I consider `Thread CPU time` as real CPU usage, and `CPU samples` as the sum of real CPU usage and the time when the thread is `RUNNABLE` in JVM perspective but is actually blocked in OS level?

Comment: @WalsonZhao Basically, yes... with the amendment that `Thread CPU time` is an accurate measure, while the time on `CPU samples` tab is the statistical approximation.

Comment: OK, thanks a lot!